# Merge Tag [reduxjs-toolkit] into [redux-toolkit]

Tags: support, retag-request, synonym-request

The name of the npm package is [`@reduxjs/toolkit`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@reduxjs/toolkit) while the package is called "Redux Toolkit".

[redux-toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redux-toolkit) is the more popular tag with 391 questions and should be the canonical (in my opinion).

[reduxjs-toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reduxjs-toolkit) is a duplicate with 16 questions and should be merged.

I submitted a potential [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/redux-toolkit/synonyms) ages ago but it seems like no one looks at or votes on these.

Comment: voted and pinged the other redux toolkit maintainers to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there were so few questions (and as this is an obvious duplicate) I went ahead and manually re-tagged them to [redux-toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redux-toolkit) myself.

The [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/redux-toolkit/synonyms) is still up for votes which would prevent the [reduxjs-toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reduxjs-toolkit) tag from being re-created.  However there are only 18 users with enough tag authority to vote on it.

Comment: I voted. Probably I was eligible.

Comment: @AjeetShah yup you are [one of the few](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/redux-toolkit/topusers).  Thanks for the vote!